# Correlation / Regression: Best way to analyse factors that influence purchase intention

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, t-test, data-visualization

I am working on my dissertation and am stuck with the data analysis section.

Topic: Luxury Fashion Influencers on Instagram: The impact of source and content factors on Gen Y and Z followers' purchase intentions in the UK

I have collected data on 5-point scales relating to the independent variables:

- Perceived credibility of the influencer (source) (this has 3 dimensions)
- Perceived psychological closeness to the influencer
- Perceived authenticity of the influencer (this has 4 dimensions)
- Perceived post originality
- Perceived post frequency

As well as the dependent variable (also a 5 point scale):

- Purchase intention

I would like to analyse if and to what extent each of the independent variables positively or negatively affects purchase intention.

I have already added the data to SSPS.

Can you please suggest the best order/way to analyse and present this information? I was thinking of regression, but I am not clear on whether to add all 5 independent variables together or do 5 separate regressions. Also, how do I account for different dimensions of a variable? I am looking for the most clear, concise and valuable way to do this.

I also have added complexity as I would like to see if there are differences in the results of Gen Y and Z. For example, I am thinking Gen Z may put more emphasis on Authenticity.

Any help or feedback would be SUPER appreciated!

Thank you,
Bianca

Comment: How is purchase intention measured?  Is it binary, continuous, ordered, etc etc.

Comment: Hi Demetri! Purchase intention was also measured on a 5-point Likert scale - 1. Strongly Disagree to 5. Strongly Agree

Answer (score 1):

Since your outcome is on a 5 point likert scale, you can use [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) to model the outcome and answer many of your questions. SPSS should have a means of doing this.

You could do 5 separate regressions (it depends on if you're asking a causal question or just a descriptive one), but it is often easiest to put everything in a regression and model it together.

If you think the effect of, say, authenticity will depend on generation born then you should include an interaction between the authencity measure and the generation measure.